# Plot Dates in MatPlotLib using a scatter data set

Tags: python, r, numpy, matplotlib

I have a large data set. I am getting an array where I get

```
arDates = DataSet["dates"].Values
```

The array should appear like that.

```
arDates =  [u'2013-11-27T02:02:50'  u'2013-11-27T00:00:00' u'2013-11-27T00:00:00'
 u'2013-11-27T00:00:00']
```

I am working to plot this and represent it in an histogram.

1- I created a line of 360 (number of days per)

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 360, 10)
daily = DataSet.groupby(lambda x: arDates[x])
plt.axis([0,360,0,100])
```

1- Should I make an histogram2D and make years as axeY, and days as axeX.
2- Can I extract dates from arrays this way :

```
daily = DataSet.groupby(lambda x: x.year())
daily = DataSet.groupby(lambda x: x.month())
daily = DataSet.groupby(lambda x: x.day())
```

so what am I doing wrong here?
I couldn't find a way to parse dates and make an 1D histogram 
I am doing it this way, but I am getting an empty figure.

DataSet["dates"].hist( color='k', alpha=0.5, normed='false')

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. There is no real question, except for "what is the best way" but that isn't necessarily connected to the code you posted and is opinion based. What about asking it in this way: "currently, my code does ... but I want it to do .... so what am I doing wrong here?"

Comment: just curious why this has the `R` tag?

Comment: yeah, but not the `pandas` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you mean:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
arDates = pd.Series(pd.DatetimeIndex([u'2013-11-27T02:02:50',  u'2013-11-25T00:00:00', u'2013-11-25T00:00:00',
    u'2013-11-25T00:00:00']).dayofyear)
arDates.hist()
plt.show()
print np.histogram(arDates)
```

Output:

```
(array([3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([ 329. ,  329.2,  329.4,  329.6,  329.8,  330. ,  330.2,  330.4,
        330.6,  330.8,  331. ]))
```